# I have this error: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name in Java application

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I built an app that counts some tax forms in a table and has to insert the number in another table.
When I count the tax forms in the first table I do it with this sql query :

```
select count(distinct cui) from dec_declaratii where id > 142321849 and 
tip_declaratie='D212' and anul_duk>=2019 and cod_stare_prelucrare_intern 
in ('DUK_VLD', 'GEN_MSJ')";
```

When I run it from Oracle Toad it works but when i put it in java and I try to get the result with rs.getString("count(distinct cui)") it gives me this error : 
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name

Why is this happening ?

What can I do to make it work ?

I tried writing count(distinct cui) with capital letters and if I write count(*) it works but I need the distinct number of tax forms.

```
public class Baza {

int idmin = 142321849;
int rezultat = 391320;

    String host = "xxx";
    String user = "xxx";
    String pass = "xxx";
    String user2 = "xxx";
    String pass2 = "xxx";

    String host2 = "xxx";
    String nr = "0";
public void conectare() {

    try {
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, user, pass);
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    String sql = "select count(distinct cui) from dec_declaratii where id 
> 142321849 and tip_declaratie='D212' and anul_duk>=2019 and 
cod_stare_prelucrare_intern in ('DUK_VLD', 'GEN_MSJ')";
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
    while(rs.next()) {
       nr = rs.getString("count(DISTINCT CUI)");
       System.out.println(nr);
    }
    }catch(Exception e) {System.out.println(e);}
    int nr2 = Integer.parseInt(nr);

    try {
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host2, user2, pass2);
     Statement st = con.createStatement();
     String sql = "update nr_tot_dec_212 set nr_dec='"+nr+"', data=sysdate 
where id=1";
     st.executeUpdate(sql);


    }catch(Exception e) {System.out.println(e);}
 }

}
```

I would like to get the result of the query : select count(distinct cui) from dec_declaratii where id > 142321849 and tip_declaratie='D212' and anul_duk>=2019 and cod_stare_prelucrare_intern in ('DUK_VLD', 'GEN_MSJ')"; in a Java variable. It gives me this error:java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name

Comment: Where's the exception thrown? When you execute the query or when you try to get the result? In the latter case, try `rs.getString(1)` instead. Or even better `rs.getInt(1)`

Answer (score 0):

use alias for name the column of your count

```
select count(distinct cui) as cnt from dec_declaratii where id > 142321849 and 
tip_declaratie='D212' and anul_duk>=2019 and cod_stare_prelucrare_intern 
in ('DUK_VLD', 'GEN_MSJ')";
```